# What is the correct html semantic tag for short lines of text that describe and advertise product features?

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

On this [website](https://www.xt2-extenders.com/hxt2-hdmi-fiberoptic-extender/), I don't know what to use for small lines of texts which describe and promote product features. This doesn't really feel like a heading, and it also doesn't feel like a paragraph.

What would you say is the best html semantic tag for the lines of text next to the pictures, for example the "Maximum performance" element? (rudimentary simple, fiber all the way, and built to last)

Comment: Your (closely related, if not duplicate) question: [Can paragraph tags be one sentence long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58047525/1591669) -- Here too, please include a minimal HTML example in your question.

Comment: Thomas, please see my answer on that related question ([Can paragraph tags be one sentence long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047525/can-paragraph-tags-be-one-sentence-long#answer-58772532)) which addresses this directly.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to show a title and description under that.

For example you can create that with Bootstrap like this :

```html
<section class="container-fluid bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Your title at here</h3>
    <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So you would use h3 for maximum performance? What makes you say this is a heading and not a paragraph or a span?

Comment: @Thomas You said I need a layout to create a box like "Maximum performance" and I wrote that for you. Load bootstrap into your file and follow this code. First you need to learn bootstrap and then implement your page. It will be easy and simple with bootstrap.

Comment: @Mohammad the question isn't about how to achieve a certain layout, but about which html element is semantically most appropriate for the text in question—regardless of the visual layout. The question doesn't mention layout at all.