# Can paragraph tags be one sentence long?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am confused by the meaning of the paragraph tag. Some websites use paragraphs for one sentence, but it doesn't really feel like paragraphs.

Take for example [this webpage](https://www.xt2-extenders.com/hxt2-hdmi-fiberoptic-extender/). What tags would make more sense semantically for the elements "Professional Robust HDMI fiber extender for 4k video" and "HDMI 2.0 | 2160p60 | 18Gbps | HDR | 4:4:4 | HDCP 2.2"? Would you use a `span`, a `div`, or a heading for the first sentence?

Same question for the second sentence. It doesn't feel like a paragraph, it's not even a sentence. It consists of just words separated by a vertical line. Is it a `span`, a `div`, or a subheading then? On the other hand, if I use a `span`, wouldn't that indicate to search engines and screen readers that this isn't text? I mean, `span` is not semantic, whereas this second sentence provides meaning.

Same thing for the next headings down the page. Specifications, support, and ordering information are headings, no doubt about that, they introduce a new section of content. But what about "Built to last" and "Fiber all the way"? They don't really feel like the same type of headings. What is the most semantic tag for them?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use <span> instead <p>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p)

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee the duplicate question doesn't answer my question. I'm really asking what a paragraph is. I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you include a minimal HTML example that shows the element and its content in question + the necessary context? The question should still make sense if the linked example goes offline.

Comment: Yes, paragraphs can be one sentence long; without question.

Comment: Single-sentence paragraphs are common even in prose, so there is no reason the spec would discourage single-sentence `p` elements. In fact, the spec explicitly suggests (albeit informatively) not to think of `p` in prosaic terms, but in structural terms. This means that a `p` can really represent just about any self-contained run of text. Even if it's not a complete sentence. Even if it's a single word.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the "why?" of this question is "SEO & semantic HTML", it worths noting that in this particular case (as well as in many others), *it absolutely doesn't matter what tag to use*.

Not every single thing has a semantic meaning in the markup.

It's a good idea to use `<footer>...</footer>` over generic `<div>...</div>` for footer, but in case of text elements the most important thing is probably to clearly differentiate "text" with "headings".

By the way, if you lookup [the definition of paragraph](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/paragraphs), it specify only 2 particular limitations of paragraphs

1. It is some text ( good one to follow & not use `<p>` as container for `<div>`s or `<img>`s ).
2. "A paragraph begins on a new line" ( easy to follow in web environment, since different place on the page is pretty much as a "new line" in a book ).

The rest are just general observations.

It says "it is usually more than one sentence" & "there is often a blank line between paragraphs", but technically you might write two 1-word paragraphs that are separated by a " | " instead of a blank line.

Which also follows [paragraph specs](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.1).

As for `<span>` & `<div>`, according to [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV) they should be used for the same purpose (document structuring) with a difference that `<div>` is a block-level element while the `<span>` is an inline element.

So `<span>`s are basically inlined `<div>`s.

In your example site, I'd say that "Professional robust HDMI fiber extender for 4K video" is an `<h2>` or `<h3>` considering the name of e-store is an `<h1>` somewhere in the `<nav>` (it's a common practice as far as I know).

The "HDMI 2.0 | 2160p60 | 18Gbps | HDR | 4:4:4 | HDCP 2.2" should most probably be `<p>` (or an `<h4>`/`<h5>` if it's *really* important).

The "sections" of this element might or might not be wrapped in `<span>`s depending on whether you need it for styling or other purposes.

Comment: Headings are not meant to convey importance. Neither of the two lines of text would be appropriate as a heading. But the rest of your answer stands. I'd suggest that each line be marked up as its own `p` element with a different class name (so they can be styled differently).

Comment: @BoltClock I agree, this part of the answer is more about common SEO practice to "highlight" important parts with heading tags which might or might not (it's frequently not) be adequate in semantic markup.

Comment: @BoltClock even though I do think that the first piece of text ("Professional robust...") is completely appropriate as heading in this case.

Comment: Why do you think they shouldn't be headings? This is the part I'm most confused with. My goal is not necessarily to respect best SEO practices, but rather to make a webpage as semantic as possible, according to the HTML5 specification. What criteria to use to decide between heading, paragraph, and spans from a semantic point of view?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be worried unless you want to style it then use span. If not it should be in heading three or paragraph depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:** Can paragraph tags be one sentence long?

Yes, `<p>` tags can be one sentence long—just like paragraphs in the English language can be one sentence long. One of the examples used on the [`<p>: Paragraph Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) page of the MDN Web Docs uses a single-sentence paragraph as an example:

```
<p>Some species live in houses where they hunt insects attracted by artificial light.</p>
```

> **Question:** Take for example [this webpage](https://www.xt2-extenders.com/hxt2-hdmi-fiberoptic-extender/). What tags would make more sense
>   semantically for the elements "Professional Robust HDMI fiber extender
>   for 4k video" and "HDMI 2.0 | 2160p60 | 18Gbps | HDR | 4:4:4 | HDCP
>   2.2"? Would you use a span, a div, or a heading for the first sentence?

If I were writing the webpage as a text document, what would make the most sense for the main heading of the document? And in the case of an h1: what is the subject of the page? In this case, I would say that "HXT2: Professional robust HDMI fiber extender for 4K video" makes the most sense as the h1, as that is the subject of the page. The `alt` text of the image HXT2 image acts as text, so you could mark that up this way:

```
<h1><img src="HXT2.jpg" alt="HXT²"> Professional robust HDMI fiber extender for 4K video</h1>
```

The following run of text ("HDMI 2.0 | 2160p60 | 18Gbps | HDR | 4:4:4 | HDCP 2.2") is really a list of meta information, which could be semantically marked up as the unordered list that it is:

```
<ul>
  <li>HDMI 2.0</li>
  <li>2160p60</li>
  <li>18Gbps</li>
  <li>HDR</li>
  <li>4:4:4</li>
  <li>HDCP 2.2</li>
</ul>
```

> **Question:** If I use a span, wouldn't that indicate to search engines and screen readers that this isn't text?

No. While `<span>` elements don't have any special semantic meaning of their own, they don't *remove* the inherent semantics of text. Text wrapped in a `<span>` is still text, and it has no inherent affect on the way that search engines or screen readers interpret it.